# Split large json file by arrays

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, dataset

I have a large JSON file aprox 30 GB, the schema  can be observed below.

```
 {
    "AdresseList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_6043F4D9_C4CA_44d0_BE88_027166A8B008",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "adressebetegnelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_BB398854_F92E_4372_A20A_D7136BB5CD9C",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "dørbetegnelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_16B39B2F_0D4D_45ca_8164_8E1D78D202FC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "dørpunkt": {
                    "description": "EAID_2E77B0C3_49AF_47b0_AD4E_DD653B99FD0B",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "etagebetegnelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_805BB835_641D_49d5_93E6_80C8E3FFD91C",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "bygning": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst4A2C09_8035_4ca8_8AA0_CBAAB89AF135",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "husnummer": {
                    "description": "EAID_src6919CB_1734_44ef_BE5B_C115B637B2CD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "AdressepunktList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_00A7AF01_C512_4a85_ADB5_98FB15541948",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"id_lokalId
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "oprindelse_kilde": {
                    "description": "EAID_B9AAE6C5_974D_4d20_BABA_C62874774F4B.EAID_FD77FC95_714B_4779_B7FA_F9BBAB41758D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "oprindelse_nøjagtighedsklasse": {
                    "description": "EAID_B9AAE6C5_974D_4d20_BABA_C62874774F4B.EAID_B8A27494_DF27_4aa9_B1F4_EBD68D2479A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "oprindelse_registrering": {
                    "description": "EAID_B9AAE6C5_974D_4d20_BABA_C62874774F4B.EAID_10DCC555_0BE9_4991_AD8C_DEA595CB08A0",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "oprindelse_tekniskStandard": {
                    "description": "EAID_B9AAE6C5_974D_4d20_BABA_C62874774F4B.EAID_181528AD_2DA3_4e9d_BF38_81916A924D2A",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "position": {
                    "description": "EAID_4B062EDE_CE8C_414b_AB85_B5A1FD72AA78",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "HusnummerList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_D0A626FC_CCAE_4209_B2F6_AC919B74A528",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "adgangsadressebetegnelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_EDCC14FC_63ED_4ebe_8B52_3E406831A148",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "adgangspunkt": {
                    "description": "EAID_E3A37E0C_D0D8_4c30_BBD5_2F26F7A24591",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "husnummerretning": {
                    "description": "EAID_1A906922_EFAC_4182_AA8C_08332D52C6EE",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "husnummertekst": {
                    "description": "EAID_83A4C230_5C5A_4ffb_B136_0315DD9F8DBE",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejpunkt": {
                    "description": "EAID_F6BAEBD6_0306_4641_9DEA_C1441D986AFB",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "jordstykke": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst052F4B_D60C_4ccd_BAE5_6BCED78FE40C",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "placeretPåForeløbigtJordstykke": {
                    "description": "EAID_dstC82C82_CC9D_4d7d_9B8A_8F4A1ADFB5AE",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "geoDanmarkBygning": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst3C28C5_D640_4bc0_9014_FDC7CBF30581",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "adgangTilBygning": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst3E4349_6115_4191_AF4F_243CCE561C41",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "adgangTilTekniskAnlæg": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst79A4C1_23B2_4c0c_85CC_60C6E2EA5AE0",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejmidte": {
                    "description": "EAID_dstC9842D_CF82_4dc5_8114_3FF7AEF90C17",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "afstemningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_dstB6088D_EE9E_451c_8070_088AA4520FA6",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "kommuneinddeling": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst714AB4_FE21_446f_BEE5_7AE65691A45B",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "menighedsrådsafstemningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst08DF20_7055_4542_8D3D_F8FCCD9A7125",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "sogneinddeling": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst0864F0_E380_4aa6_A644_25974107FC47",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "supplerendeBynavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_dstF5C960_23DB_454c_A8A8_41B231DF61C7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "navngivenVej": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst74C4B5_0F0F_4a51_B317_BA74938B605F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "postnummer": {
                    "description": "EAID_dst3F5BA7_EB6C_47a2_AC4B_90C72D4F3585",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "NavngivenVejList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_0CB629B5_8D1F_486c_A319_717EDF879B82",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "administreresAfKommune": {
                    "description": "EAID_31D3BE04_2F70_4092_8381_5517A5543634",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "beskrivelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_C132D872_7F07_4ebf_BC6B_37049F2E5EB8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "udtaltVejnavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_788F8478_A747_412d_9DE6_FEE0DB4C1BFA",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejadresseringsnavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_9621DD9D_50E3_4426_AB5A_A5E43DED4B05",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_CA00150C_5B5C_4c32_AE72_A7EE5AEDE015",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_oprindelse_kilde": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_7F8EB510_AD02_4fd5_844B_C9AB17FB1798.EAID_FD77FC95_714B_4779_B7FA_F9BBAB41758D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_oprindelse_nøjagtighedsklasse": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_7F8EB510_AD02_4fd5_844B_C9AB17FB1798.EAID_B8A27494_DF27_4aa9_B1F4_EBD68D2479A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_oprindelse_registrering": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_7F8EB510_AD02_4fd5_844B_C9AB17FB1798.EAID_10DCC555_0BE9_4991_AD8C_DEA595CB08A0",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_oprindelse_tekniskStandard": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_7F8EB510_AD02_4fd5_844B_C9AB17FB1798.EAID_181528AD_2DA3_4e9d_BF38_81916A924D2A",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_vejnavnelinje": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_93C24B4D_0641_4073_B260_1EC7F2024CF4",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_vejnavneområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_1C496CD9_4541_4574_974D_B641F186077F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejnavnebeliggenhed_vejtilslutningspunkter": {
                    "description": "EAID_4C594A8E_797B_40bb_B60D_0E5C9159DCD3.EAID_C3E042F2_A66E_40f4_92A1_7C7024A30D16",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "NavngivenVejKommunedelList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_34D070E5_DD89_4984_8054_16BA70936EA0",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "kommune": {
                    "description": "EAID_0A04B5E9_9F12_49cb_B2AF_AFEE0315AE2B",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "vejkode": {
                    "description": "EAID_852A683F_3E30_4009_A003_B3C8F6F76930",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "navngivenVej": {
                    "description": "EAID_dstE87A3E_ECA3_4f38_A586_117287E4754A",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "NavngivenVejPostnummerList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_EA75B9ED_59CD_4d67_A340_A1CB578CC1B7",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "navngivenVej": {
                    "description": "EAID_1B3CAEB0_80FA_486f_ABD1_818B332C905C",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "postnummer": {
                    "description": "EAID_AD2844E3_7F05_4d8d_967E_44BA3D12C4B4",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "NavngivenVejSupplerendeBynavnList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_5F14BDC8_7D97_433b_B28D_F8A56A1B9F13",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "navngivenVej": {
                    "description": "EAID_7CF789EC_31C0_4af3_B75B_77674A26DECD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "supplerendeBynavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_21C0B8C7_8B67_406c_BDC1_21ADBA284867",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "PostnummerList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_449B3570_F0F7_494e_9756_D49E60644CD0",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "navn": {
                    "description": "EAID_9E7FA46D_52D9_4615_B24C_599BB28D1923",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "postnr": {
                    "description": "EAID_8F8BACBF_E985_4dc1_BCF4_27F5C3FD0BB1",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "postnummerinddeling": {
                    "description": "EAID_E5F5DDF9_3CF4_4304_B02D_E67AB0CDD619",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "SupplerendeBynavnList": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "description": "EAID_9D39B21D_E73C_4f1b_9C6C_B75412DAAD77",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "forretningshændelse": {
                    "description": "EAID_1CE948DD_FC3D_4638_8913_A2D35A00F64D",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsområde": {
                    "description": "EAID_C955CFEC_E2A0_47da_9F76_6452FCC9E4E2",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "forretningsproces": {
                    "description": "EAID_A9A40479_E58D_4c7a_A0EA_F8EC4829ECAC",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_namespace": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_6CEB0356_5CBF_4159_B96B_A2489DD2DAC8",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "id_lokalId": {
                    "description": "EAID_D273E3D8_A3F4_41bc_AF9C_E67B4A29C008.EAID_9AB90AE0_9F85_4164_9B25_8EB2139D65A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_96862BAA_95CA_46aa_A6A0_757327A10BF7",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "registreringsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_9F724D2B_7763_4997_8C85_580610BABC1F",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "registreringTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_301BF58F_26E7_4d1f_B7B6_3881F8C1B0A5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "status": {
                    "description": "EAID_22AF1E6A_73A8_4c89_96EB_C307235DFD19",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningFra": {
                    "description": "EAID_AB768062_FD24_4960_8AA1_C6BFF90C00C5",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "virkningsaktør": {
                    "description": "EAID_8E60197F_D857_47c6_8611_75B63D0940FD",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "virkningTil": {
                    "description": "EAID_3058C5FD_9824_48ba_B62C_C24587BF6537",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"],
                    "format": "date-time"
                },
                "navn": {
                    "description": "EAID_8359992A_59C4_48c4_981D_7A42F20CA168",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                },
                "supplerendeBynavn": {
                    "description": "EAID_C6722E9B_EF6C_425d_9373_A933C01A6A64",
                    "type": ["string",
                    "null"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to split this large document into a file for each array but I couldn't find a method, I tried to make a bash script using jq but with no succes, the script can also be seen below

```
for f in $(jq -r 'keys[]') ; do
  jq ".[\"$f\"]" < input.json > "$f.json"
done < input.json
```

Does somebody know a way for spliting the file with bash or any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple python3 script:

```
import json

json_file = open('file.json')
parsed = json.load(json_file)

for key, value in parsed.items():
    new_json = open(key + '.json', 'a')
    new_json.write(json.dumps(value))
    new_json.close()

json_file.close()
```

Comment: I tried it but the program gets killed most likely because the file is too large

Comment: Ah sorry. hadn't thought of that. It seems try to parse the whole file. [ijson](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) should handle it.